# BASH scripts selectively working

Tags: shell-script, bashrc

I have a number of BASH functions, which I have had in my `/etc/bash.bashrc` for a long time.  They work there, in `~/.bashrc`, and in OSX's `~/.bash_profile` when written like this:

```
mcdir(){
    mkdir "$1";
    eval cd "$1";
}
```

This is just a short one, which I use daily, as an example.  It simply makes a given directory and changes to it, the way `mkdir "$1" && cd "$1"` would do... I'm just lazy.

The point is that it works... I know it works, because I've been using it for years.

Now, I have recently removed it from my `bashrc` and put it into `/usr/local/bin` as `mcdir` (as well as `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/mcdir`), so that there really aren't any changes.  Here, it looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir "$1";
eval cd "$1";
```

This, for all intents and purposes, should work exactly like the above function.  The problem is that it only works halfway.  It will make the new directory, but *NEVER* change into it.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here, and/or how to solve it?

---

Another example I have is a `cdd` function... in `bashrc` it looks like this:

```
cdd(){
    cd "$1";
    echo -e "\033[101m" $(pwd) "\033[49m";
    ls -l;
}
```

And that works perfectly!  But, when I put it into its own script in `/usr/local/bin` and make it executable, like this:

```
cd "$1";
echo -e "\033[101m" $(pwd) "\033[49m";
ls -l;
```

It doesn't actually change into the directory.  It will give me the `pwd` and the `ls -l`, but I won't change directory at all.

Comment: The script does create the dir, it does change directory to go in it, and then that script (launched in a subshell) exits, and you are back in your current shell, in its (former) current directory.

Comment: @OlivierDulac Thanks... that clears it up, pretty well.  So it's *technically* working, just not in the active shell I want it to.  Is there any way to force it to work in the current, active shell... or to manipulate the current, active shell?

Comment: @antiDill You can `source` a script to have it run it the current shell, e.g. `source script.sh`. I mention that in my solution. A common technique is to source other scripts from your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @antiDill I've updated my solution to include a recommendation for organizing your `~/.bashrc` into separate files.

Comment: @OlivierDulac @igal Thank you both... I have done some tinkering around, and you're both correct.  It adds a couple of lines to my `bashrc`, but a net-loss of several lines.  Not *exactly* what I was hoping for, but better than nothing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scripts run in subshells. They can't affect the environment of your active shell session in the way that functions can. See, for example, the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide, Chapter 21: Subshells](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html):

> A subshell is a separate instance of the command processor -- the *shell* that gives you the prompt at the console or in an *xterm* window. Just as your commands are interpreted at the command-line prompt, similarly does a script [batch-process](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/timedate.html#BATCHPROCREF) a list of commands. Each shell script running is, in effect, a subprocess (*child process*) of the [parent](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html#FORKREF) shell.

Or the [Bash Reference Manual, Section 3.8: Shell Scripts](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Scripts.html#Shell-Scripts):

> A shell script may be made executable by using the chmod command to turn on the execute bit. When Bash finds such a file while searching the `$PATH` for a command, it spawns a subshell to execute it. In other words, executing
>
> `filename arguments`
>
> is equivalent to executing
>
> `bash filename arguments`
>
> if `filename` is an executable shell script. This subshell reinitializes itself, so that the effect is as if a new shell had been invoked to interpret the script, with the exception that the locations of commands remembered by the parent (see the description of `hash` in [Bourne Shell Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins)) are retained by the child.

If you want to use a script instead of a function you can `source` it instead of executing it, but honestly I think it's probably better to just stick to using functions (or aliases) for the kind of thing you're doing.

That said, if you want to reorganize the code in your `~/.bashrc` then you can break it up into separate files and then `source` those files from `~/.bashrc`, e.g. you can put them in a local subdirectory such as `~/.bashrc.d`.

Comment: You say "can't" as if it's not possible, whatsoever.  Is this true, or is there a workaround?

Comment: @antiDill Well, anything is possible in principle. You might be able to write a script that runs some code that goes into RAM and modifies your active shell session (or something like that - way out of my depth there) but that wouldn't be a supported use-case. Give me a second and I'll add a couple of references.

Comment: Thank you.  I was just trying to "tidy" up my `bashrc` because it's *LOADED* with little aliases and functions, like this... I was able to put my aliases in `/etc/profile.d/00-aliases.sh`, and that saved some room, but I was hoping to do better... I guess I'll have to leave some elements in there.

Comment: @antiDill : things involving 'cd' will have to stay in your bashrc.

Comment: @OlivierDulac, *or* be `source`d from the `.bashrc`.